# How to remove Inbound rule from Azure loadbalancer

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have an Azure loadbalancer v2 created and wish to remove a rule from it.
So, I will get a load balancer object:

```
$loadBalancer = Get-AzureLoadBalancer -Name myLoadbalancer -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup
```

Then, I will try to remove a rule:

```
Remove-AzureLoadBalancerInboundNatRuleConfig -LoadBalancer $loadBalancer -Name RuleName
```

But, the rule stays there... Maybe I am missing something obvious? There is no examples which i can base on :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cmdlets with “Config” suffix only change in-memory data ($loadBalancer object in this case).

After Remove-AzureLoadBalancerInboundNatRuleConfig -LoadBalancer $loadBalancer -Name RuleName

Do  Set-AzureLoadBalancer -LoadBalancer $loadBalancer

Let me know

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood - it is not working like this.
I was able to reach this goal by using same resource manager template, which is used to provision this resource and modifying it to remove/update required rules